# How to add Height to specific coordinates in meter in the attribute table in QGIS 3.22.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, field-calculator, elevation

I would like to add the height/elevation of a specific topographic point into my attribute table. I  calculate x- and y- coordinates as well as the dms-coordinates in the field calculator by code and would then like to add the height in meter above sea level, preferably by code in the field calculator or by plugin. CRS is ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N.

Comment: Do you have access to a DTM (Digital Terrain Model) for the area of interest?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to a DTM.